# Smoothness of Ricci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, regularity-theory-of-pdes, ricci-flow

Consider the solution $g_t$ to the Ricci flow equation $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = -2\text{Ric }g$ on a compact manifold $M$ with initial metric $g_0$. This is probably very elementary, but I was wondering how can we prove that the solution $g_t$ is smooth in space? Also, as far as I know, the solution $g_t$ is smooth in time as well. Is there an easy proof for that? Thanks!

Comment: Most books on Ricci flow prove the existence problem. You can take a look at the following pdf:https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nsher/ricciflow.pdf

Comment: @Enigma Yes, the existence is fine. But I don't see how the ${\bf smoothness}$ of the metric (both in space and time) follows. At least, I don't think it follows trivially from the existence theorem in the pdf that you link to.

Comment: I think the idea is that using Deturck's trick, the Ricci flow is reduced to a parabolic system. Therefore, you can use the standard results for parabolic systems to get the smoothness.

Comment: Three-manifolds with positive Ricci curvature, Richard Hamilton. If you look at this article, Hamilton proves the smoothness.

Comment: "Deforming Metrics in the Direction of their Ricci Tensors", Dennis Deturck. Basically he turns the Ricci flow into an equivalent system that is homogenous linear parabolic system

Comment: You can look up the smoothness for parabolic systems in Evan's PDE text.